# Knockout observable is not updating when Chosen dropdown value changes

Tags: knockout.js, webpack, jquery-chosen, commonjs

We have been using `Chosen` library with `RequireJs` and `KnockOut`. Everything was working fine until we switched from `RequireJS` to `commonjs` and now using `webpack` to bundle. The issue is that the `knockout observable` does not get updated when we change the value in `chosen` dropdown.

Here's the javascript code that was working using `RequireJs`.

```
define(['knockout', 'text!./employee-setup.html', 'utils', 'panel-section', 'toastr', 'jquery', 'knockout-postbox', 'knockout-projections', 'chosen', 'jsteps'], function (ko, template, utils, PanelSection, toastr, $, _, _, _, jsteps) {
function EmployeeSetup(params) {
    var self = this;
    this.agentTypes = ko.observableArray();
    this.agentType = ko.observable();


    this.loadAgentTypes = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Employee/GetAgentTypes',
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                if (utils.handleAjaxResult(result) && result.Data) {
                    self.agentTypes([]);

                    var agentType = [{ ID: "", Name: "" }];

                    $.each(result.Data, function (i, item) {
                        agentType.push({ID: item.ID, Name: item.Name});
                    });
                    self.agentTypes(agentType);
                    $('#agentType').chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true, width: '310px' });
                    $('#agentType').trigger("chosen:updated");
                } else {
                }

            },
            error: function () {
                toastr.error('Could not load agent types');
            }
        });
    };
    self.loadAgentTypes();
    };
 return { template: template, viewModel: EmployeeSetup };
});
```

The html for that component:

```
<div class="input-container" data-bind="">
     <select data-bind="value: agentType, options: agentTypes, optionsText: 'Name'" data-placeholder="Select Agent Type..." id="agentType" class="chosen-select sp-uin-dropdown" tabindex="2"> </select>
</div>
```

Here's the code using `commonjs`

```
var ko = require('knockout'),
    utils = require('utils'),
    PanelSection = require('panel-section'),
    toastr = require('toastr'),
    $ = require('jquery');
require('knockout-postbox');

function ViewModel(params) {
   var self = this;
   this.agentTypes = ko.observableArray();
   this.agentType = ko.observable();

   this.loadAgentTypes = function () {
   $.ajax({
       url: '/Employee/GetAgentTypes',
       method: 'POST',
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function (result) {
       if (utils.handleAjaxResult(result) && result.Data) {
              self.agentTypes([]);

              var agentType = [{ ID: "", Name: "" }];

              $.each(result.Data, function (i, item) {
                  agentType.push({ID: item.ID, Name: item.Name});
              });
              self.agentTypes(agentType);
              $('#agentType').chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true, width: '310px' });
              $('#agentType').trigger("chosen:updated");
            } else {
           }
        },
        error: function () {
           toastr.error('Could not load agent types');
        }
    });
  };
  self.loadAgentTypes();
}
module.exports = { viewModel: ViewModel, template: require('./template.html')      };
```

And it's using the same `html` file as above.

In the `webpack.config.js` we define the path to `jquery` and `chosen`.

It loads the `chosen dropdown` correctly. However, when I `subscribe` to observable it doesn't update value when dropdown changes. I only see the value from console once on initial load.

```
self.agentType.subscribe(function (value) {
    console.log('value', value);
}, this)
```

Few posts here in SO suggested to use `bindingHandlers`. I have tried this working code from [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6A57J/64/) in my application, but I only get the value from initial load.

Any suggestion on how to resolve this issue or what is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by `webpack`. In order to resolve the issue, my colleague wrote a custom `bindingHandler`.

`HTML` code:

```
<div class="input-container">
 <select data-bind="
                value: agentType,
                options: agentTypes, 
                optionsText: 'Name',
                dropdown: {
                    width: '310px',
                    allow_single_deselect: true
                } "
                data-placeholder="Select Agent Type..." id="agentType">
</select>
```

Custom `bindingHandler`:

```
// a dropdown handler, which currently utilizes the Chosen library

ko.bindingHandlers.dropdown = {

    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext){

        // get chosen element

        var $element = $(element);

        // get options (if any) to pass to chosen when creating

        var options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());



        // NOTE: when using Chosen w/ webpack, the knockout bindings no longer

        // fired. This event handler is to remedy that. It watches the change

        // event for the underlying <select> (which chosen updates), and

        // updates the corresponding observables mapped to value and selectedOptions.

        // Only one should be bound, value for single select, selectedOptions for multi-select

        // binding direction: Knockout <- Chosen

        $element.on('change', function(e, item) {

            var valueProp = allBindings.has('value') && allBindings.get('value');

            var selectedOptionsProp = allBindings.has('selectedOptions') && allBindings.get('selectedOptions');

            if (item) {

                if (allBindings.has('options')) {

                    var allOptions = ko.unwrap(allBindings.get('options'));

                    if (valueProp) {

                        // single select

                        if (ko.isObservable(valueProp)) {

                            if (!item.isMultiple) {

                                if (item.selecting) {

                                    valueProp(allOptions[item.index]);

                                } else {

                                    valueProp(null);

                                }

                            }

                        }

                    }

                    if (selectedOptionsProp) {

                        // multi select

                        if (ko.isObservable(selectedOptionsProp)) {

                            if (item.isMultiple) {

                                // handle multi select

                                if (item.selecting) {

                                    // select

                                    selectedOptionsProp.push(allOptions[item.index]);

                                } else {

                                    // deselect

                                    selectedOptionsProp.remove(allOptions[item.index]);

                                }

                            }

                        }

                    }

                }

            } else {

                // this is triggered w/o args when the control is reset. This happens when deselecting during single-select

                if (valueProp) {

                    // single select

                    if (item === undefined && ko.isObservable(valueProp)) {

                        valueProp(null);

                    }

                }

            }

        });
        // handle updating the chosen component's UI when the underlying

        // options, selectedOptions or value changes

        // binding direction: Knockout -> Chosen

        ['options', 'selectedOptions', 'value'].forEach(function(propName){

            if (allBindings.has(propName)){

               var prop = allBindings.get(propName);

                if (ko.isObservable(prop)){

                    //console.log('subscribing to:', propName, ' for:', $element);

                    prop.subscribe(function(value){

                        if (value != null) {

                            //console.log('calling chosen:updated');

                            var options = ko.unwrap(allBindings.get('options'));

                            // console.log('got options:', options);

                            if (options) {

                                if (options.indexOf(value) > -1) {

                                    // item is in options

                                    //        console.log('value is in options:', value);

                                } else {

                                    // item is not in options, try to match ID

                                    options.some(function (item) {

                                        if (item.ID == value) {

                                            // update the obs. to the entire item, not the ID

                                            prop(item);

                                        }

                                    });

                                }

                            }

                        }

                        $element.trigger('chosen:updated');

                    });

                }

            }

        });       

        // add chosen css class (not sure this is needed)

        $element.addClass('chosen-select');



        // create chosen element, passing in options if any were specified

       if (typeof options === 'object') {

            $element.chosen(options);

        } else {

            $element.chosen();

        }

        $element.trigger('chosen:updated');

    }

};
```